# Duvida quanto ao import e uso global do Axios no Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios

Estou utilizando o Axios em um dos meus projetos com Vuejs, minha duvida está ligada diretamente a forma de import global do plugin. Atualmente estou fazendo assim:

Crie um arquivo /plugin/axios.js com este código:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Axios from 'axios'

Axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://minha-api/'

Vue.use({
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.prototype.$http = Axios
    }
})
```

E no main.js fiz o import do arquivo acima.

Cheguei a pensar em ignorar o /plugins/axios.js e fazer o import diretório no main.js desta forma:

```
...
import Axios from 'axios'

Axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/'

Vue.prototype.$http = Axios
....
```

Se possível gostaria ainda de entender o que seria esse:

```
Vue.use({
    install(Vue) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [documentação](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin) explica como usar/criar plugins, mas basicamente funciona assim:

Para utilizar um plugin você precisa *"instalar"* ele na sua instância usando o método [`Vue.use()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use). Este método global vai chamar o método `MeuPlugin.install()` quando um plugin for instalado ([veja no código fonte do Vue.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/6fe07ebf5ab3fea1860c59fe7cdd2ec1b760f9b0/src/core/global-api/use.js)).

Então a explicação mais simples é que o método `install` seria como um *callback*, ou talvez um, "construtor" do plugin para que quando o programador decidir usá-lo na sua aplicação este método execute todas as preparações para que o plugin funcione corretamente quando for usado.

---

No código fonte do [`Vue.use()`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/6fe07ebf5ab3fea1860c59fe7cdd2ec1b760f9b0/src/core/global-api/use.js) tem o código:

```
if (typeof plugin.install === 'function') {
      plugin.install.apply(plugin, args)
} else if (typeof plugin === 'function') {
      plugin.apply(null, args)
}
```

Ou seja, você pode passar um objeto que tenha o método `install` ou passar um classe que será instanciada.

Então para criar um plugin você poderia usar um objeto com uma propriedade `install` que seja uma função

```
let meu_plugin = {
    install: function(Vue) {
        // código do plugin
    }
}
Vue.use(meu_plugin)
```

Você também poderia usar diretamente dentro do `Vue.use()` como no exemplo que você postou:

```
Vue.use({
    install: function(Vue) {
        // código do plugin
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma você estaria instalando o axios como um plugin.
Facilitaria acessa-lo dentro de um component utilizando um `this.$http.get()` mas creio que para uma abordagem um pouco mais abrangente, utiliza-lo como um singleton simples seria melhor. Pense que você poderá precisar do axios dentro de uma action do Vuex por exemplo.

Comment: Como seria esse uso como singleton?